# How to extract and pivot in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like following

I treid to sum score in pivoted style..

```
product date        score
A      2020/8/1      1
B      2018/8/1      2
B      2018/9/1      1
C      2017/9/1      2
```

I'd like to transform them to the following `pivoted`one.
The index is `YEAR(t.date)` and `columns = product`

```
date   A    B   C
2017   0    0   2
2018   0    3   0
2019   0    0   0
2020   1    0   0
```

Are there any effective way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can handle this by joining a calendar table containing all years of interest to your current table, aggregating by year, and then using conditional aggregation to find the sum of scores for each product.

```
WITH years AS (
    SELECT 2017 AS year FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2018 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2019 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 FROM dual
)

SELECT
    y.year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.product = 'A' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.product = 'B' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.product = 'C' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM years y
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON y.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t."date")
GROUP BY
    y.year
ORDER BY
    y.year;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `PIVOT` Clause after determining the year range, and joining outerly with your data source and setting the null scores as zeroes :

```
WITH years AS
 (SELECT MIN(EXTRACT(year from "date")) AS min_year,
         MAX(EXTRACT(year from "date")) AS max_year
    FROM tab)
SELECT year, NVL(A,0) AS A, NVL(B,0) AS B, NVL(C,0) AS C
  FROM (SELECT l.year, product, SUM(score) AS score
          FROM tab t --> your original data source
         RIGHT JOIN (SELECT level + min_year - 1 AS year
                      FROM years
                   CONNECT BY level BETWEEN 1 AND max_year - min_year + 1) l
            ON l.year = EXTRACT(year from "date")
         GROUP BY l.year, product)
 PIVOT (SUM(score) FOR product IN('A' AS "A", 'B' AS "B", 'C' AS "C"))
 ORDER BY year;


YEAR    A   B   C
----    -   -   -
2017    0   0   2
2018    0   3   0
2019    0   0   0
2020    1   0   0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5667bdc335281130c95938a17d8607d8)</kbd>